# Quotation marks don't display properly in notification inbox for bounties

Tags: bug, bounties, notifications

I realize that this is something of an edge case, and not really a huge problem, but it's a bug, nonetheless.

When a notification about a bounty shows up in the notifications inbox, and the title of the [question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/48020/5323) has single quotation marks, the quotation marks break ( *example below* )

[image]

.....I don't recall seeing this on other notifications for this bounty (the three day and one day warning), but here it is at bounty's end.

Comment: @Doorknob I do believe you're right. Voted to close.